# IVR call simulation on Asterisk 15 server

Tags: asterisk, sip, ivr, dtmf

I am using Asterisk 15 server and wanted to configure IVR call simulation. My configuration scenario is 
1. A subscriber will register to Asterisk server and start a call.
2. The IVR audio will come from the Asterisk sever to sbscriber. 
3. Once the subscriber pressed the botton, the call will connect to a number based on DTMF digit pressed by subscriber. Then call will continue for 30 seconds.

I observered for normal call pjsip.conf file is used for configuration of a subscribers.

Could you please help me on below queries ?
1. Which file we need to configure for the IVR call simulation ?
2. Please suggest a good documentation for IVR simulation.

Answer (score -1):

Files are extensions.conf and pjsip.conf/sip.conf

You have read book for beginner, for example "Asterisk the future of telephony".

After that write dialling core or reuse vicidial.org or other core and write dialplan in extensions.conf for you ivr.

What you tried to do usually called "press-1 outbound dialling campaign"